# How to get the default vsftpd.conf by installing vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-14.04, apt, vsftpd

I am installing a new server and I have been adjusting my vsftpd settings when it suddenly stopped working. I noticed that the service vsftpd only worked if the `vsftpd.conf` was empty or deleted. So I decided to reinstall vsftpd using `apt-get remove vsftpd` and `apt-get install vsftpd` but the `vsftpd.conf` file which I deleted before because I wanted to start all over with the configartion keeps missing.

How can I reinstall vsftpd so I get back my vsftpd.conf file?

Comment: The vsftpd.conf file is just text use your favourite editor to create it.

Comment: @lain What about the default contents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you were using yum then `yum remove vsftpd` would remove the configuration files and installing it again would place the default vsftpd as well.

The package manager of Ubuntu works different. `--purge` needs to be issued to remove configuration files as well. If vsftpd is installed again the default vsftpd config file will be placed.

Note that the folder needs to be backed up before uninstalling it, as --purge will remove the configuration files

Comment: `apt-get remove vsftpd --purge` ..then `apt-get install vsftpd` to install it again with original configuration files at `/etc/vsftpd.conf` .

Comment: Yup, `--purge` was what I was looking for.